# How to retrieve data of anonymous account when sign out ? Firebase authentication anonymous

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

**Context**

In my signup/login activity, users can authenticate anonymously and I store them in my database with their FirebaseID as primary key. 
Here's the code:

```
 anonymous_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Task<AuthResult> resultTask = mAuth.signInAnonymously();
            resultTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
                    // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                    Log.d(TAG, "signInAnonymously:success");
                    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                    gotodownload_from_database();
                }
            });
```

### **Issue**

If my users sign out and then if they want to log as anonymous, it will create another account and they will not be able to retrieve their previous anonymous account. How can I make it possible to retrieve their old anonymous account and their data ? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are saying is happening only if you are sign-in out, deleting the user account directly from the Firebase Console or if you uninstall the app. So, you can use Firebase anonymous authentication to create and use only **temporary** anonymous accounts to authenticate with Firebase but `anonymous authentication accounts` don't persist across application uninstalls. When an application is uninstalled, everything that was saved locally will be deleted, including the anonymous `auth token` that identifies that account. **Unfortunatelly, there is no easy way to reclaim that token for the user**.

Instead, you should encourage all your users to fully log in with a supported account provider (`Google`, `Fabcebook`, `Twitter` and so on) so that they can log in from all their devices without worry of losing their data.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Oh ok so there is an issue in my code. When I sign up with the code above in anonymous and then if I sign out `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Login_activity.class);
                startActivity(intent); ` I go back to my Login_activity. Then if I use the code in my question, it creates a new FirebaseId so a new account.

Comment: Yes I've understood that it will not recreate another account. But in my case (I tested it) it recreates another, so there is a problem in my code that I don't understand. Do you know why it recreate another account ? (and this is not normal I've understodd).

Comment: I cannot see any problem with your sing-in code. But let me be clear. Anonymous users don't expire unless but you sign-out using `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut()`. If you do so, it means that next time you want to sing-in again, a new anonymous user is generated. That's why is called an anonymous user, so it can be available only in one "session".  If you sign-out and sing-in again another `a new uid` is generated. So in case of Firebase anonymous authentication, there is no need to sign-out. You need to sign-out when you are using (google, facebook etc) authentication process, ok?

Comment: Ok I understand now thanks. So the ways an anonymous user can lost his session are 1) User uninstalls the app 2)By using signout method 3) ? if he clear cache or data of his app ? (I suppose it, tell me if I'm wrong). Is what I'm saying sounds good ? Thanks a lot